# ora-00907 missing right parenthesis date

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I keep getting this message when I'm creating this table on my oracle JDBC, and I don't know what's wrong (but I can execute this query on a MySQL server, for example). Can anyone wonders why I'm keeping getting that?

```
CREATE TABLE temporarytable ( 
 thetype     INT4, 
 acode       INT4, 
 acodea      INT4 DEFAULT 0, 
 aname       VARCHAR(50), 
 anameb      VARCHAR(50), 
 agcodec     VARCHAR(16), 
 agnome      VARCHAR(40), 
 acoded      INT4, 
 abname      VARCHAR(80), 
 ancode      INT4, 
 clieone     VARCHAR(80), 
 adate       DATE, 
 aqtifromi   NUMERIC(20, 6) NULL DEFAULT 0, 
 avaluei     NUMERIC(20, 6) NULL DEFAULT 0, 
 discxxtt    NUMERIC(20, 6) NULL DEFAULT 0, 
 somemore    NUMERIC(20, 6) NULL DEFAULT 0, 
 gaining     NUMERIC(20, 6) NULL DEFAULT 0, 
 valcms      NUMERIC(20, 6) NULL DEFAULT 0, 
 liqidd      NUMERIC(20, 6) NULL DEFAULT 0, 
 theback     NUMERIC(20, 6) NULL DEFAULT 0, 
 theprct     NUMERIC(20, 6) NULL DEFAULT 0, 
 somesll     NUMERIC(20, 6) NULL DEFAULT 0, 
 theccod     INTEGER 
)
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Let's get this squared away: On which database do you want to run this `CREATE TABLE` statement, and on which database did you get that error message?

Comment: If you're creating a table in an Oracle database you need to [use Oracle data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html). These aren't even native MySQL data types, [but they are mapped there](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/other-vendor-data-types.html).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understands, but I'm configuring a generic JDBC server by AquaDataStudio and creating table on this database and running on it. The MSQL database was another database  that I did this just to check.

Comment: MySQL <> Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I think I've solve it.

it was complaining about the:

```
NULL DEFAULT 0
```

So after I changed to DEFAULT 0 it worked after I've changed some types for Oracle database compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to add `NULL` before `DEFAULT 0` is meaningless, and even if to add `DEFAULT NULL` is so.

> Since, if a column doesn' have a `DEFAULT` value, implicitly has
>   `NULL` as default value.

Moreover there's no data type `INT4` in oracle, use `INTEGER` instead :

```
CREATE TABLE temporarytable ( 
 thetype     INTEGER, 
 acode       INTEGER, 
 acodea      INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
 aname       VARCHAR(50), 
 anameb      VARCHAR(50), 
 agcodec     VARCHAR(16), 
 agnome      VARCHAR(40), 
 acoded      INTEGER, 
 abname      VARCHAR(80), 
 ancode      INTEGER, 
 clieone     VARCHAR(80), 
 adate       DATE, 
 aqtifromi   NUMERIC(20, 6) DEFAULT 0, 
 avaluei     NUMERIC(20, 6) DEFAULT 0, 
 discxxtt    NUMERIC(20, 6) DEFAULT 0, 
 somemore    NUMERIC(20, 6) DEFAULT 0, 
 gaining     NUMERIC(20, 6) DEFAULT 0, 
 valcms      NUMERIC(20, 6) DEFAULT 0, 
 liqidd      NUMERIC(20, 6) DEFAULT 0, 
 theback     NUMERIC(20, 6) DEFAULT 0, 
 theprct     NUMERIC(20, 6) DEFAULT 0, 
 somesll     NUMERIC(20, 6) DEFAULT 0, 
 theccod     INTEGER  
);
```